# How can I import a CSV containing headers and rows of data into a custom hierarchical taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I have a CSV of 4000 models of vehicle. The headers are "Year", "Type", "Make", "Model". I also have a custom taxonomy called "vehicles". I would like to create the hierarchy of unique cells in each column as a taxonomy, but I can't seem to find an appropriate solution. 

Here is a small subset:

```
2005    Alphasports Sport   Cobra 180   ....
2005    Alphasports Sport   Cobra 90    ....
2005    Alphasports Utility Overland 180    ....
2005    Alphasports Utility Winchester 180  ....
2005    Alphasports Youth   Daisy 90 P2 ....
2005    Alphasports Youth   Kolt 90     ....
2005    Alphasports Youth   Mini Cobra 50   ....
2004    Arctic Cat  Sport   400 DVX     ....
2005    Arctic Cat  Sport   400 DVX     ....
2006    Arctic Cat  Sport   250 DVX     ....
2006    Arctic Cat  Sport   250 DVX P2  ....
```

As you can see, there are repeating years, brands, types, etc. What I would like is a taxonomy in WooCommerce, to use with WOOF for filtering such that when the user selects "YEAR" they can then select from the unique list of "BRANDS" available from that year, and then the "TYPE" and "MODEL" in the same way, such that when they have selected they have chosen YEAR->BRAND->TYPE->MODEL and my available parts that correspond with that filter selection will show.

I've tried using WP All Import, but it only creates each new taxonomy as it's own entry, ie. rather than creating a hierarchical structure like 2005->Alphasports->Sport->Cobra 180, it just creates an entry "2005 Alphasports Sport Cobra 180". I may not be using it correctly, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm not bad with php/mysql and am thinking maybe I can just write a script to create the taxonomy, but I don't really know how to enter all of those into the database directly.

I'm using WOOF, but I'm not opposed to just creating everything myself if need be. As long as I can get the taxonomies structured properly, I'll be good to go, I just know that there has to be an easier way than entering them in, or exporting each unique iteration and importing them in really small subsets.

Comment: check this [importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Comment: thank you for replying. what i'm looking for is more of an importer of taxonomy rather than of actual products or posts. I just need to create the hierarchy using a CSV. any ideas?